# Data loss during high speed transfer over SocketChannel

Tags: java, android, networking, nio, socketchannel

I'm developing Android application, where to phones performing some computation over `Wifi-Direct`.
In my case efficiency is critical. Bottleneck of my protocol is a network. I use `SocketChannel` to receive/transmit data. 
Here is my pseudo-code:

```
byte[] array = new byte[]{20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20};
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            ByteBuffer sendBB = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffSize);
            sendBB.put(array, 0, array.length);
            sendBB.rewind();
            ByteBuffer receiveBB = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffSize);

            try {

                socketChannel.read(receiveBB);
                socketChannel.write(sendBB);

                byte[] received = new byte[10];
                receiveBB.rewind();
                receiveBB.get(received, 0, 10);
                Log.i("Received", Arrays.toString(received));           


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Similar code is for other party.
Connection is created like this:

```
serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(socketAddress);           
socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
```

It turned out, that everything is transmitted well, when `buffSize` is small : 100, 200.
When it is 500 and higher I have a data loss. I receive something like:

```
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
[20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
```

Higher buffer gives way higher speed. Is there a way, how to keep a speed and prevent data loss?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by looping reading and writing :

```
int countWritten=0;
while (countWritten < buffSize)
{
    countWritten+=socketChannel.write(sendBB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usual problems.

```
socketChannel.read(receiveBB);
socketChannel.write(sendBB);
```

You're ignoring the lengths returned by `read()` and `write()`.

```
byte[] received = new byte[10];
receiveBB.rewind();
receiveBB.get(received, 0, 10);
```

This is all wrong. It should be:

```
int count = socketChannel.read(receiveBB);
byte[] received = new byte[count];
receiveBB.flip();
receiveBB.get(received);
receiveBB.compact();
```

If you're expecting fixed-length messages you have to loop until you get them all. `read()` isn't obliged to fill the buffer.

Comment: In my case, I want to transmit small messages e.g.10 bytes. I put them into big ByteBuffer for faster transmission.

Comment: @Sparrow_ua Whatever the size of your buffer, there is still no guarantee that read() will fill it on the first call, nor that write() will effectively write it all in a single call. Reading the javadoc for [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) and [write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)), you can see that the number of bytes read or written can be from 0 up to the buffer's `remaining()`size

Comment: I looped through read and write methods(to make sure, that everything is read/written), but it slows down transmission very badly. Is there any other way for quick transmission?